# How to Invoke a Javascript function on the content of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, string

I am developing a WordPress page, where it's required to call a javascript function (given below) to transform the text to title case or sentence case. I found some scripts from previous posts, which I would like to use. however, I do not know how to call it inside a DIV or a paragraph.

this is the script that I would like to use. any help to improve this script is welcome.

PS: I do not want to use the CSS method to transform the text.

```js
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  var i, j, str, lowers, uppers;
  str = this.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });

  // Certain minor words should be left lowercase unless 
  // they are the first or last words in the string
  lowers = ['A', 'An', 'The', 'And', 'But', 'Or', 'For', 'Nor', 'As', 'At',
    'By', 'For', 'From', 'In', 'Into', 'Near', 'Of', 'On', 'Onto', 'To', 'With'
  ];
  for (i = 0, j = lowers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\s' + lowers[i] + '\\s', 'g'),
      function(txt) {
        return txt.toLowerCase();
      });

  // Certain words such as initialisms or acronyms should be left uppercase
  uppers = ['Id', 'Tv'];
  for (i = 0, j = uppers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + uppers[i] + '\\b', 'g'),
      uppers[i].toUpperCase());

  return str;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not run "inside a DIV". You're completely mixing concepts here.

Comment: _" I do not want to use the CSS method to transform the text."_ - why not?

Comment: hi my bad, for not clarifying my question. what I want is to call/run the function using a "class" or "ID". hope that clarifies.

Comment: I do not want to use CSS because it does not take care of conjunctions and prepositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the function you need to retrieve all the target elements, in the example below I used `div` elements but a class or any other valid selector would work, and from there you need to invoke the `toTitleCase()` string prototype on the text content of each element. It could look something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(el => el.textContent = el.textContent.toTitleCase());
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  var i, j, str, lowers, uppers;
  str = this.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });

  // Certain minor words should be left lowercase unless 
  // they are the first or last words in the string
  lowers = ['A', 'An', 'The', 'And', 'But', 'Or', 'For', 'Nor', 'As', 'At',
    'By', 'For', 'From', 'In', 'Into', 'Near', 'Of', 'On', 'Onto', 'To', 'With'
  ];
  for (i = 0, j = lowers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\s' + lowers[i] + '\\s', 'g'),
      function(txt) {
        return txt.toLowerCase();
      });

  // Certain words such as initialisms or acronyms should be left uppercase
  uppers = ['Id', 'Tv'];
  for (i = 0, j = uppers.length; i < j; i++)
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + uppers[i] + '\\b', 'g'),
      uppers[i].toUpperCase());

  return str;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach(el => el.textContent = el.textContent.toTitleCase());
```

```html
<h3 class="title">This is an example of title case</h3>
<p>This is paragraph text and will not be changed.</p>
```

Comment: Roy a quick question, is it possible to include transforming text to Sentence case in this script? please advise.

Comment: It would be possible, but CSS `text-transform: capitalize` should take care of that unless you have a special use case.

Comment: Yes, Roy, there is a special use. I want it to take care of Nouns, proper nouns, etc... something similar to the Title case code I posted

Comment: In that case the pattern used in the `toTitleCase()` function could be applied there, so long as you have an exhaustive list of the various nouns you want to retain capitalisation on.